# Filter returns much more objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Album name')

class AlbumImage(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(PhotoAlbum, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, blank=True)
```

When i send GET request without query parameters i see a normal response like (one random entry):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Album name",
        "photos": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_one.png"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_two.png"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And there is a problem! When i overrided the method `get_query_set` like:

```
has_photos = self.request.query_params.get('has_photos')
if has_photos == 'true':
    return PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(photos__isnull=False)
elif has_photos == 'false':
    return PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(photos__isnull=True)
```

In the case `has_photos = 'true'` i see the response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Album name",
        "photos": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_one.png"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_two.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Album name",
        "photos": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_one.png"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_two.png"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It returns **one entry for each photo object in photos**.

So if, the photo album has 10 associated `AlbumImage` objects in `photos` it returns 10 similar entries instead of 1.

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `get_queryset` method has an issue.
You can remove duplicated `album` objects with `distinct` method.

This problem occurs because a join occurs while evaluating a query.

## As-is

```
has_photos = self.request.query_params.get('has_photos')
if has_photos == 'true':
    return PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(photos__isnull=False)
elif has_photos == 'false':
    return PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(photos__isnull=True)
```

## To-be (1)

```
has_photos = self.request.query_params.get('has_photos')
if has_photos == 'true':
    return PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(photos__isnull=False).distinct()
elif has_photos == 'false':
    return PhotoAlbum.objects.filter(photos__isnull=True).distinct()
```

## To-be (2)

```
qs = PhotoAlbum.objects.annotate(count=Count('photos'))
has_photos = self.request.query_params.get('has_photos')
if has_photos == 'true':
    return qs.filter(count__gte=1)
elif has_photos == 'false':
    return qs.filter(count=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a possible solution, but i guess there is a more global problem in filter. I'd like to know how can i filter without repetition in my case.

Comment: Then, you should avoid using a join in your query. Because using `__` symbol to refer a foreign key usually means that a join is in your raw sql query, you should write without `__`. For example, `PhotoAlbum.objects.annotate(count=Count('photos')).filter(count__gte=1)`.

Comment: Nice, what is more optimal to use for a big db?

Comment: I just added "To-be (2)".

Comment: Uhm.... not sure but, annotate way, which is (2), could be more optimal. During join, (1) brings all fields of AlbumImage Model, on the other hand, (2) brings only count of AlbumImage Model

Comment: Okay, thanks. What about `prefetchrelated` in this case? will it be slower?

Comment: Yes, you can use prefetch to speed up queries.